# need to make web page dispaly after fething the data in Next.js

Tags: node.js, api, next.js

I'm using Next.js, where im new to Next.js; I have some knowledge in javaScript
I have written some code to get the API of my JSON_file(which is my data that needs to be displayed in /blogs webpage);

```
import React from 'react'

const blogs = () => {
 var element
 (async()=>{

  var data=await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api")
  data=await data.json();
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.length)
  for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
     element = data[index];
    // document.getElementById(tilte).innerHTML+=element["title"]
    console.log(element["title"])
  }
})()
```

in this above code, I have written some code to fetch data from API, but the above-commented code( document.getElementById(tilte).innerHTML+=element["title"] ) is not working and getting error as( Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML') ) but I wanted to print this in my web page so I tried to print in return function which also does not worked

```
  return (
    <>
    <div><h1>
      Welcome to my  blogs
    </h1>
    </div>
  
    <div id="tilte">
          {console.log(element["title"])}
    </div>
    </>
  )
  
}


export default blogs
```

in this, I tried to console.log my element variable in the return function but I'm getting undefined, I understood that this is because JavaScript has Asynchronous behavior

I tried to make blogs export function async and aw

```
  const blogs = async () => {
  var element
  await (async () => {
```

but given as an error( Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead )

even I tried some other options of putting return function inside iife but this will not even display welcome to my blogs line

hoping for solution,,

Answer (score 1):

Try using `useEffect()` with `useState()` to update the state of the blog once you fetch the data, like this:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const Blogs = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const func = async () =>{
      let data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api");
      data = await data.json();
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.length);
      for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        setContent ((prevState) => prevState + data[index]);
      }
    }
    func();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div><h1>
        Welcome to my  blogs
      </h1>
      </div>

      <div id="tilte">
        {content}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: is there any option without using react hooks

Comment: You can try to do it with `getServerSideProps` or with `getStaticProps` https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview